# Count, Join Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-workbench

I am working on a database which depicts the scenario of a football pitch divided into X Y coordinates.

I have a table called 'location' which has the columns locID, X_C, Y_C.  For the unique ID of a goal scored with its coordinate.

My second table called 'goals' is a list of goals scored with a date/time details.  Its FK is locID which links the two tables and allows the DB to track location of a goal with its time/date etc.

I am trying to query which coordinate the most goals have been scored which I believe would start with a count query using locID followed by a join of the 'goals' table but I am struggling to make this work. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Desired results would be a X column and Y column with a 'goals scored' column in desc order.

Comment: Hi. You mention a tool for recording & querying designs. You need to read a textbook on what a design is & what a query is. What is your reference? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please read & act on [ask], the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. PS Please edit clarifications into your post, not comments. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something similar to:

```
SELECT location.locID, COUNT(goals.goalID) FROM location JOIN goals ON goals.locID=location.locID GROUP BY location.locID;
```

Here we select the location id along with the count of goals on that location from a join of location and goals tables with shared locID and grouping the result by locID.